UK visa refusal because trip costs two months of my salary
I am from Pakistan and today I received a UK visa refusal.

I applied from Pakistan.
I'm employed here in a local company deriving a monthly salary of 240000/- per month.
I have provided my job contract with the company, my six months salary slips, job leave letter from employer, ending balance of about 7000/- pounds.
I was planning to spend 8 days in the UK, and provided my day to day trip, hotel reservations, flight reservations, my property documents, father's death certificate, mother's affidavit that I am the person who takes care of her, my engagement certificate

The refusal is on V4.2(a) and (c): the visa officer was not satisfied. He asked how I can spend 1200/- pound on a short visit and he said this is almost double and half of your salary and this is the only reason he gave me in my refusal.
How can I get a visa for this visit?

Could you convert your monthly salary also in British pound, so we can help better.

@GiacomoCatenazzi it's about £660 - I was thinking the same.

The question is: why do you take such expensive holiday in UK, considering it will ruin your finances? The visa officers may think the real reason is just to immigrate in UK and work illegally there. It is not easy to solve such problem, and also personally I think it is not a good idea to spend so much. I just think you should wait more time.

You might review this older question and its extensive answer for an excellent examination of what UKVI is looking for in UK visa applications. I agree with Giacomo Catenazzi's comment: it's most likely UKVI sees your application as unreasonable or unbelievable, as you proposed to expend so much of your savings for a brief holiday.

How much do you usually spend each month? How much is left? Isn't £1200 a lot when your monthly salary is about £660? And if you are engaged, one may wonder why you are going on holiday alone. And if you have to take care of your mother, one way wonder who is going to take care of her while you are away. Also remember that the minimum wage in the UK is nearly 3 times your salary, so you look like an ideal candidate for immigration.

None of the amounts posted makes any sense to me. Where is 2½ times 240000/- mentioned? Are you using different currencies but formatting them the same?

@WeatherVane my understanding is that the salary is in PKR (so about £660) while the rest is in pounds. Doesn’t quite come up to 2.5 but we’re probably missing some data.

How can I get a visa for this visit? Why is it apparently so important to get to the UK? Plenty of other destinations for an 8 day trip.

1000/- is not a typical way to write UK currency.  £1000.00 is more common or just £1000.  In an international context, £ might be inconvenient to type or confusing.  1000GBP is a good format in this context.  Using the unfamiliar format 1000/- makes it harder to distinguish currencies.  Use GBP and PKR.

As I understand from your other questions this is your second refusal in four months. If you apply again this is likely to increase their suspicion that you have other intentions for visiting the UK.

Where did the  £7000  in your account come from? At  £660 a month salary it likely took you many years to save up all of this.  Also how do you get away with spending only  £1200 on your trip? That barely covers the flights. Hotels and food are going to cost you at least a thousand more, making the cost four months of your salary. Nobody spends 4 months salary on an 8 day vacation.

@DJClayworth The source of some of the £7k could be €5,000 from The Netherlands which the OP mentions receiving in an earlier question as part of a voluntary departure arrangement.

@DJClayworth I have, in the past, spent over 1.5 month's salary on a simple 6 day trip. Such is life when one is working in a poorer country: You still want to travel, so you save up. Some people save up an entire year to go on a holiday, some take loans for the same purpose. This group is riskier for overstaying of course, but I do think that (ignoring my personal feelings about UK being a boring travel destination) refusing people solely because they're from a poorer area and will spend large quantities (that they do have) isn't exactly fair.
